# PayPal sandbox - none of payments in the Business's account history

Tags: asp.net, paypal

'm using the project http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers to test the PayPal's sandbox. I have a sandbox account, inside it I have a business account (for some reason I see `Business    Unverified`) and also a `Personal   Verified` account to do some payments. After running that project, i process to payment using that `Personal` account data. After the payment completes I still don't see that payment in my `Business` account. Why ?

Comment: Did you try logging in to the sandbox BEFORE testing the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've figured it out.

I had to provide int the `Web.config` file my own `PayPalUsername` (that sandbox business account email),

`PDTToken` ([using that tutorial](https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/How-to-use-PayPal/PDT-Token-Payment-Data-Transfer/td-p/288))

`APIUsername`,`APIPassword`,`APISignature` ([using that tutorial](http://www.putler.com/support/faq/how-to-get-paypal-api-username-password-and-signature-information/))

Answer (score 1):

**Try this to verify your business account**

1. Go to your Test Accounts page
2. Select the Unverified account.
3. Click the Enter Sandbox Test Site button.

A new window will pop up that looks very much like the actual www.paypal.com, except it says PayPal Sandbox at the top and a text saying Test Site below it. E-mail of the Test Account should be filled out already.

1. Enter the password (that you hopefully remember or noted down) and sign in.
2. Go to the My Account Overview page.

Below the “Welcome, Test User” header, it should say “Status: Unverified. Get verified”.

1. Click on that “Get verified”-link.

From here the process might vary a bit depending on what country you selected for the test account. I selected United Kingdom (or rather, it was the default and I didn’t bother changing it).

1. On the “Get verified by linking your bank account”-page, click on the “Link Bank Account”-button.

Routing number and Account number should be filled out already.

1. Fill out Bank name, if you feel like it
2. Click Continue.
3. Put whatever you feel like in the two “Confirm deposits-fields.
4. Click Submit.

Done. It should say “Bank account confirmed”. Also, if you go back and refresh the Test Accounts page, it should say Verified on the account.

Comment: thank for the description. But after I fill the Bank Name and click Save button, I get the error: 'We are sorry, we are experiencing temporary difficulties. Please try again later. If this error occurred while making a payment, avoid duplicate payments by checking your Account Overview before resending a payment.

Message 4002'

Comment: Get in touch with pay pal support as this is a paypal sandbox issue. It should allow you to verify your account. After that is done if your payments are going through it will come up in your account.

Comment: unfortunately, I re-created a sandbox account (also business and personal) and now the business account is verified, but the payment is still not visible